# Can't Stop Simultaneous Step Execution in Shell Script That Opens Mousepad GUI Windows

Tags: shell-script, systemd, xfce

```
#!/bin/sh
...several lines of commands...
mousepad file.txt
zenity --info
...several more lines of commands...
exit
```

**Expected behavior:** I command the script (in this case, via a keyboard shortcut). A **Mousepad** window then opens on my **Xfce4** desktop, displaying the contents of **file.txt**. I perform some text manipulation within same and then manually close said **Mousepad** window. *Next*, the commanded **Zenity** window appears, as expected. I close same manually and the next step of the script executes.

The script works fine if there are no other open **Mousepad** windows anywhere. However, if I happen to ***already have*** one or more **Mousepad** windows open when I command said script (again, via a keyboard shortcut), **here is what now happens:**

After said script is so commanded, the expected **Mousepad** window (the one displaying the contents of **file.txt**) opens, *along with* the **Zenity** window (note that, in this case, said **Zenity** window opens *before* the **Mousepad** window is manually closed by me).  This is undesired behavior.

Note that the subject script worked fine when running under **Debian Wheezy** (using **SystemV**). However, after a recent upgrade to **Debian Jessie** (using **systemd**) I started seeing the changed, undesired behavior. Don't know if said **systemd** plays into this...

I have tried many things, including the `wait` command and appending the `mousepad` line with  `&&`. I've also attempted trapping. Nothing is working for me.

What is causing this to happen and how can I remedy it?

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is what happens when a program runs some sort of server so that new instances connect to the existing one. If `mousapad` is running already, it just connects to the existing instance and exits immediately. Since it exits immediately, your script continues and that's why you see `zenity`.

The fix is simple, there's an option to disable this:

```
$ mousepad -h
Usage:
  mousepad [OPTION…] [FILES...]

Help Options:
  -h, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  --disable-server         Do not register with the D-BUS session message bus
  -q, --quit               Quit a running Mousepad instance
  -v, --version            Print version information and exit
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

The option is `--disable-server` so simply change your script to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
...several lines of commands...
mousepad --disable-server file.txt
zenity --info
...several more lines of commands...
exit
```

Comment: Work great now! Apparently, during the upgrade mentioned in the OP, **Mousepad** adopted a server scheme. I might have caught that myself, except for the fact that I never looked past `man mousepad`, where the required option is NOT addressed. **Lesson Learned:** When researching application options, check the _help_ page IN ADDITION TO the _man_ page...

Comment: @Digger huh, that's odd. I guessed this was the case from the behavior you described, and I installed mousepad on my system to check. To my surprise, there was no `man` page and all I could find was the `mousepad -h` :)

Comment: Please bear in mind that I'm a little behind with my upgrades...I'm currently rocking version 0.3.0 of **Mousepad**.